# In ggplot geom_ribbon is not shown in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to seperate my legend in two. One for geom_lines and one for geom_ribbons. Anyway, I was able to build a legend for geom_lines, but not for geom_ribbons.

```
test <- ggplot(UG.1.1, aes(x = Jahr))+
  geom_point(aes(y = Frühlingsanfang, colour= "Frühlingsanfang"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Frühlingsanfang,colour= "Frühlingsanfang")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Vegetationsmaximum,colour= "Vegetationsmaximum")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Vegetationsmaximum,colour= "Vegetationsmaximum")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Herbstanfang,colour= "Herbstanfang")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Herbstanfang,colour= "Herbstanfang")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Frühlingsanfang_Min, ymax = Frühlingsanfang_Max),
              fill="lightgreen",alpha=0.3) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Herbstanfang_Min, ymax = Herbstanfang_Max),
              fill="brown",alpha=0.3) +
  scale_colour_manual("",
                          breaks = c("Herbstanfang", "Vegetationsmaximum", "Frühlingsanfang"),
                          values = c("green","brown","red"))+
  scale_fill_manual("",
                    breaks = c("Standardabweichung/Herbst","Standardabweichung/Frühling"),
                    labels= c("Standardabweichung/Herbstanfang","Standardabweichung/Frühlingsanfang"),
                    values = "brown","lightgreen") +
  xlab("Jahr") +
  scale_y_continuous("Tag im Jahr", limits = c(50,320)) +
  labs(title = "Phänologischer Jahresverlauf im UG.1.1")
```

Until here my plot look like this:

[image]

I guess there is something wrong in my `scale...` -command?!

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You could try setting the order for the legends manually: `guides(color = guide_legend(order=1), fill = guide_legend(order=2))`

Comment: Hey Bari, the legend doesn't show up because your fill in geom_ribbon call doesn't match what you define in scale_fill_manual(). Try this, geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Frühlingsanfang_Min, ymax = Frühlingsanfang_Max,fill=""Frühlingsanfang"))

Comment: and scale_fill_manual(values=c("Frühlingsanfang"="lightgreen"))

Comment: Without any data, all we can do is guess, but making multiple of the same geom and hardcoding values inside `aes` are both signs that your data isn't in the appropriate shape for ggplot. There are a lot of SO posts on reshaping data for ggplot. In order to get a legend for an aesthetic, you have to actually assign a variable to it inside an `aes`—manually setting a color doesn't make a legend

Comment: Also, the `values` argument in a scale needs to be a vector—you likely forgot the `c()` around your colors